# Multiple objects calling another method method

Tags: java

In my system aircraft move randomly and when a condition is meet they send a document to the central station, this means that it can happen that some aircraft send a document at the point in time.

```
class SingleCentralStation{
    public sendDocument(Document document){
        //do something
    }
}

class Spacecraft{
    private SingleCentralStation singleCentralStation;

    public Spacecraft(SingleCentralStation singleCentralStation){
        this.singleCentralStation = singleCentralStation;
    }

    public sendDocumentToCentralStation(Document document){
        singleCentralStation.sendDocument(document);
    }
}

class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleCentralStation centralStation = new SingleCentralStation(); // singleton

        Spacecraft spacecraft1 = new Spacecraft(centralStation);
        Spacecraft spacecraft2 = new Spacecraft(centralStation);
        Spacecraft spacecraft3 = new Spacecraft(centralStation);
        Spacecraft spacecraft4 = new Spacecraft(centralStation);
        Spacecraft spacecraft5 = new Spacecraft(centralStation);

        // let's imagine that spacecrafts decide to send a document to central station all at the same point in time
        spacecraft1.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft2.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft3.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft4.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft5.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Multiple objects calling another method at the same time is possible?
- if not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to call `SingleCentralStation#sendDocument()` method at the same time. The example you have given

```
        spacecraft1.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft2.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft3.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft4.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
        spacecraft5.sendDocumentToCentralStation(new Document());
```

These are actually sequential calls executed one after the another.

You will have to handle multithreading scenarios if are going to make `SingleCentralStation#sendDocument()` call concurrently.

`P.S.`: No need to handle concurrency if `SingleCentralStation#sendDocument()` is using all local variables and is not using any state changing class level variables.

Comment: in the case that all aircraft send documents at the same point in time, there is no issue if the method contains only local variable. Right?